# In R, How to count the total number of items in a vector greater than the absolute value of 1

Tags: r, vector, absolute-value

I want to count the total number of items in a vector greater than (`>`) the absolute value of 1.

```
vec <- c(5,3,-7,0,0,0,-1,0,3,1,-3,4,7)
```

the result should exclude `0`, `1` and `-1` in the count and return the total count of `7`

attempt

```
sum(vec >abs(1))
# this returns '5' instead of '7'
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem was caused by a slip in the code and will probably help nobody else, hence, I'll cast a close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `abs` should be on the 'vec' and not on 1

```
sum(abs(vec) > 1)
[1] 7
```